# Transform a specific group of records from MongoDB

Tags: apache-flink

I've got a periodically triggered batch job which writes data into a MongoDB. The job needs about 10 minutes and after that I would like to receive this data and do some transformations with Apache Flink (Mapping, Filtering, Cleaning...). There are some dependencies between the records which means I have to process them together. For example I like to transform all records from the latest batch job where the customer id is 45666. The result would be one aggregated record.

Are there any best practices or ways to do that without implementing everything by myself (get distict customer ids from latest job, for each customer select records and transform, flag the transformed customers, etc....)?

I'm not able to stream it because I have to transform multiple records together and not one by one.

Currently I'm using Spring Batch, MongoDB, Kafka and thinking about Apache Flink.

Comment: Just want to point out that even though you must transform multiple records together, it may make sense to do this with stateful streaming. Flink will let you hold records in state until you have all the pieces required to produce results. This may or may not be a good idea, of course, depending on your other requirements.

Comment: I'm only sure that there are no further information for a group until the whole source file is read and that could be between 10 and 35 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Conceivably you could connect the MongoDB change stream to Flink and use that as the basis for the task you describe. The fact that 10-35 GB of data is involved doesn't rule out using Flink streaming, as you can configure Flink to spill to disk if its state can't fit on the heap.

I would want to understand the situation better before concluding that this is a sensible approach, however.

Comment: Let's assume that I have a 30 GB CSV flat file. On the first row of that file there is a entry from Customer_1 with [type=B, cus_id=1]. On the last row of the file there is a second entry from Customer_1 with [type=A, zip=1234, cus_id=1]. Means that the second entry of that customer has more and different information than the first one. I don't want to process and insert the first entry withouth knowing there will be a second/different one. I will process/insert [type=A, zip=1234, cus_id=1] -> like a upsert.